# An Issue about the single quote in bibliography using 'natbib' with 'agsm'

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I used `natbib` with `agsm` sytle in the bibliography. The Journal article title is within the single quote. Can I change the single quote to the double quote? Thanks a lot!

The latex codes are :

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

Find the `agsm.bst` file. Copy it to `myagsm.bst` file.

Open the file `myagsm.bst`, change

```
{ "`" swap$ * "'" * }
```

in the Function `{quote}` to

```
{ "``" swap$ * "''" * }
```

In my file, that is in line 158. Then the single quote will be changed to double quotes.

Now you can use

```
\bibliographystyle{myagsm}
```

to get the changed output.

Comment: Great that you found out how to solved this! But please do not change system files. Instead make a copy of `agsm.bst` and **rename** it. In fact this is what the license of the file asks you to do: *Copying of this file is authorized only if either (1) you make absolutely no changes to your copy, including name, or (2) if you do make changes, you name it something other than `btxbst.doc`, `plain.bst`, `unsrt.bst`, `alpha.bst`, `abbrv.bst`, `agsm.bst`, `dcu.bst` or `kluwer.bst`.* So if I understand correctly, you would be in violation of that clause.

Comment: Yes, what I did was make a copy and changed the copied file

Comment: If you also renamed the copied file, all is well. I suggest you add this important detail to your answer.